# simplified if else

Tags: c#

```
if (File.Exists(file.csv))
{
   return file.csv;
}
else if (File.Exists(file.dbf))
{
   return file.dbf;
}
```

Can I simplify this expression using one line?

Comment: Could you please reedit your post with valid C#? Broken code is hard to optimize at all.

Comment: Use the [`?:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C.23) operator? But remember, just because something is on one line doesn't make it more "optimal", just less readable.

Comment: @ebeeb: Are you talking about the missing semicolons? It shouldn't be too hard to mentally add them...

Comment: File.Exist() don't exists. It should be File.Exists()

Comment: `File.Exist()` takes a string like `"file.csv"`. I cannot comprehend what you try to achieve with `return file.csv`. Is it your purpose to return the filename if the file exists? Wrap this into a method.

Comment: @ebeeb Its File.Exists ... with an 's'.

Comment: @Azhar Khorasany: it's "doesn't exist" ... without an 's' :-D My first intend is trying to understand what the OP tries to achieve instead of altering a couple of horrible code lines into a horrible single liner.

Comment: All of you telling him his code is invalid, especially @ebeeb and ken2k : Have you thought about the possibility that `file` is a variable of a custom class with two properties `csv` and `dbf` of type `string`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: you're right, I've overseen that because I'm so used to CamelCasing.

Comment: File.Exists() is **evil**, don't use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're willing to accept an `InvalidOperationException` if no matching file exists:

```
return new[]{file.csv, file.dbf}.First(File.Exists);
```

**Edit:**

If you don't want an exception (you removed that part from your question), use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) instead and check for `null`, as Willem Duncan mentioned already in his comment.

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault()` and check for `null` to get away from the exception.

Comment: @WillemDuncan: The OP *wants* an exception.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: seems like  the OP removed the whole `else` case instead of the else keyword and the braces only, like you actually meant with your answer?

Comment: @ebeeb: Indeed. I didn't realize he removed it in the meantime.

Answer (score 6):

Not in a way that is still readable.
You could however extract that code into its own method.

Furthermore, the `else` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I see no advantages in doing this in one line, but as an alternative, maybe you could do:

```
var files = new[] { "file.csv", "file.dbf" };
foreach (var file in files)
{
    if (File.Exists(file))     
    {      
        return file;
    }       
}
```

This one is more extensible and has no repetition of strings.

Comment: @Hedi: Why very bad answer? Explain please. I would like to learn.

Comment: I actually like this answer due to it's extendability.  But, yeah, user1765862 wants all that in one line.

Comment: the "if" statement could be executed 2 times here in addition to the loop. the code posted in the question is more optimized

Comment: I mean it sounds like a single line but in reality it's not

Comment: @Hedi: are you serious? Do you actually think that this has any measurable effect in a business application? Please put things in perspective. Don't avoid doing things because of the wrong reasons.

Comment: @HediNaily: That's nonsense. The `if` is executed just as many times as in the original code. If `file.csv` exists, the code executes the `return` statement: One `if` executed. If `file.csv` doesn't exist but `file.dbf` does two `if`s will be executed, just as in the original code.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth then this answer doesn't provide a simplest code ;) don't forget the loop statement

Comment: @HediNaily: Obviously, this answer doesn't provide a solution in one line. There are no comments needed to see that. But it provides one without repetitive code

Comment: @Hedi: you are missing the point. Please reread comments. Actually, the answer of Dominic Kexel is about the same (but uses LINQ). Do you understand now?

Comment: While it's not a single line, the answer is not bad. The only thing that I probably would do differently is using an implicit infered array like `var files = new[] {file.csv, file.dbf}` instead of using a `List<string>` because I think it's more readable and you really don't care about the type of the collection, since you just iterate it once.

Comment: @Dominic: yes, that would be better. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

One line: Yes. Delete all newlines except the last.

One simple statement: No.  Your code conditionally returns.  I doubt there is a single simple command in C# that does that.